# Problem of group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group under matrix addition (entries belong to $\mathbb Z$) and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ consisting of matrices with even entries. Then how to find the order of quotient group $G/H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  Think firstly about the case of $2\times2$ matrices.  The quotient group is the set of cosets of $H$.  So to put it roughly, you are asking: how many "separate" matrices do you need to add to elements of $H$ in order to get all elements of $G$?

For example, since $H$ contains all matrices (you didn't actually say "all" but I expect that is the question) which look like
$$\pmatrix{even&even\cr even&even\cr}\ ,$$
you can add
$$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$$
to these and you will get all matrices which look like
$$\pmatrix{odd&even\cr even&even\cr}\ .$$
Can you take it from here?

Of course this is only an "informal" explanation but I hope it helps.

Comment: yes I got it..thank you so much.